# Map Table/Columns dynamic entity framework

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, dynamic

I´m try to map column to properties using ef 4 dynamically but i dont know how to do that.

My class has data annotation reference the table column name like that.

```
[Table(Name = "TB_CLIENTE_HUB")]
public class ClienteRepository : Repository<ClienteRepository>, IDisposable
{
    [Column(Name = "ID_CLIENT")]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "NOME")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "SOBRENOME")]
    public string Sobrenome { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "CPF")]
    public string CPF { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "EMAIL")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "SEXO")]
    public string Sexo { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DT_NASCIMENTO")]
    public DateTime? DataNascimento { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "ESTADO_CIVIL")]
    public string EstadoCivil { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "SENHA")]
    public string Senha { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DDD")]
    public string DDD { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "CELULAR")]
    public string Celular { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "TIPO_LOGRADOURO")]
    public string TipoLogradouro { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "LOGRADOURO")]
    public string Logradouro { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "NUMERO")]
    public string Numero { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "COMPLEMENTO")]
    public string Complemento { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "BAIRRO")]
    public string Bairro { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "CIDADE")]
    public string Cidade { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "CEP")]
    public string CEP { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "UF")]
    public string UF { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DT_CADASTRO")]
    public DateTime? DataCadastro { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DT_ATUALIZACAO")]
    public DateTime? DataAtualizacao { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "FG_ATIVO")]
    public bool? IsAtivo { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "DT_ATIVACAO")]
    public DateTime? DataAtivacao { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "FG_PRIMEIRO_ACESSO")]
    public bool? IsPrimeiroAcesso { get; set; }
    [Column(Name = "ID_FACEBOOK")]
    public string FacebookId { get; set; }
}
```

So in my DbContext i have the follow lines...

```
public class DAOContext : DbContext
{
    public DAOContext() : base("name=defaultConnection")
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<DAOContext>(null);            
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        var maps = Util.GetMapping();            
        foreach (var map in maps)
        {

            var config = modelBuilder.GetType().GetMethod("Entity").MakeGenericMethod(map.ClassType).Invoke(modelBuilder, null);

            config.GetType().InvokeMember("ToTable", BindingFlags.InvokeMethod, null, config,
                                                        new object[] {map.TableName});

            var hasKey = config.GetType().GetMethod("HasKey");
            var paramEx = Expression.Parameter(map.ClassType, "m");
            var lambdaEx = Expression.Lambda(Expression.Property(paramEx, "Id"), paramEx);

            hasKey.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Int32)).Invoke(config, new object[] { lambdaEx });

            var prop = Expression.Property(paramEx, "Id");
            var lambdaEx2 = Expression.Lambda(prop, paramEx);
            var ignore = config.GetType().GetMethod("Ignore").MakeGenericMethod(prop.Type);

            var property = config.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new Type[] { lambdaEx.GetType() });

        }

    }}
```

In this line

```
var property = config.GetType().GetMethod("Property", new Type[] { lambdaEx.GetType() });
```

the property is null, so i would like to know how to call the method

```
config.Property(t => t.Id).HasColumnName("ID_CLIENT");
```

Comment: Erm, why? If you've got data annotations, why do the fluent mapping? I think I'm missing your point.

Comment: The GenericDataAccess is an project that will do all relation to database, this library don't known nothing about other project that will be referenced by they, he's will looking for entity class with annotations in anyone project that has references to GenericDataAccess and will save data to database.